# The number with the biggest number of repetitions within an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was asked an interview question which asked me to return the number with the biggest repetition within an array, for example, {1,1,2,3,4} returns 1.

I first proposed a method in hashtable, which requires space complexity O(n).
Then I said sort the array first and then go through it then we can find the number.

Which requires O(NlogN)

The interviewer was still not satisfied.

Any optimization?

Thanks.

Comment: Bucket sort still requires O(n) space, and the interwiever was not satisfied with it, it appears.

Comment: do the number in array has a scope?

Comment: They weren't satisfied with the hashtable solution, that runs in O(n), you can't beat that

Comment: Maybe it was about the space complexity, also O(n) for hashtable.

Comment: @Byakuya I'm pretty sure you can't do better than O(n) space if you want O(n) time, and sorting can use no extra space

Comment: @aaronman I wish I could disagree.

Comment: @Byakuya I find it hard to believe that the interviewer had a problem with the solutions themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interviewers aren't always looking for solutions per se. Sometimes they're looking to find out your capacity to do other things. You should have asked if there there were any constraints on the data such as:

- is it already sorted?
- are the values limited to a certain range?

This establishes your ability to *think* about problems rather than just blindly vomit forth stuff that you've read in textbooks. For example, if it's already sorted, you can do it in O(n) time, O(1) space simply by looking for the run with the largest size.

If it's unsorted but limited to the values `1..100`, you can still do it in O(n) time, O(1) space by creating a count of each possible value, initially all set to zero, then incrementing for each item.

Then ask the interviewer other things like:

- What sort of behaviour do they want if there are two numbers with the same count?
- If they're not satisfied with your provided solutions, try to get a clue as to where they're thinking. Do they think it can be done in O(log N) or O(1)? Interviews are *never* a one-way street.

There are boundless other "solutions" like stashing the whole thing into a class so that you can perform other optimisations (such as caching the information, or using a different data structures which makes the operation faster). Discussing these with your interviewer will give them a chance to see you in action.

> As an aside, I tell my children to always show working out in their school assignments. If they just plop down the answer and it's wrong, they'll get nothing. However, if they show their working out and get the wrong answer, the teacher can at least see that they had the right idea (they probably just made one little mistake along the way).
>
> It's exactly the same thing here. If you simply say "hashtable" and the interviewer has a different idea, that'll be a pretty short interview question.
>
> However, saying "based on unsorted arrays, no possibility of keeping the data in a different data structure, and no limitations on the data values, it would appear hashtables are the most efficient way, BUT, if there was some other information I'm not yet privy to, there might be a better method" will show that you've given it some thought, and possibly open a dialogue with the interviewer that will help you out.

Bottom line, when an interviewer asks you a question, don't always assume it's as straightforward as you initially think. Apart from tech knowledge, they may be looking to see how you approach problem solving, how you handle Kobayashi-Maru-type problems, how you'll work in a team, how you'll treat difficult customers, whether you're a closet psychopath and endless other possibilities.

Comment: Isn't your solution for limited values actually O(n) space, being a simple hashtable method?

Comment: @Byakuya, no, because N is the number of items rather than the range. The range is 1..100 whether there are five or a billion items, hence the space complexity is constant. In any case, I removed the pseudo-code since it's not really relevant to the answer. Sometimes I just add too much damn detail :-)

Comment: Oh, right, so it would be O(k), k being the numer of possibilities, but still not O(1) ;).

Comment: Can you also point out the fact that the interviewer might just be a moron, with an unsorted array and no limit to range those are essentially the best solutions, it's also pretty fair to assume the array wasn't sorted since the OP suggested sorting as a solution

Comment: @Byakuya, O(1) _is_ O(k), same as O(3n+72) is O(n). Complexity analysis usually chooses the fastest increasing term based on the input size. In the case of `1 vs k`, they both increase at the same rate (ie, not at all).

Comment: Well, I meant a similar solution which would adjust to any possible-set, so it would be O(n) time and O(k) space complexity.

Comment: @aaronman, the _OP_ suggested sorting, I see no evidence that the _interviewer_ said it was _unsorted._ In fact, the sample array given _was_ sorted so, at a minimum, OP should have clarified. That's what I meant when I stated you need to _discuss_ the thought processes and possible other bits of information you don't yet have. Of course, a helpful interviewer may have asked why OP thought sorting was necessary, though probably in a less obvious manner.

Comment: @paxdiablo I wasn't at the interview, but the whole thing seems suspect to me, it's a bit cruel to shoot someone down for offering those two solutions. At that point you should at least get a hint instead of just being told your solution isn't good enough

Comment: @aaronman, yes, I agree with that, and have done so in some of my interviews. When I'm on the other side of the table, I don't let interviewers get away with that though, if they state my solutions aren't good enough, I'm technically competent enough to say they are in the absence of more info. Being able to draw out that info from reluctant interviewers(/customers) is also a vital skill :-)

Comment: @aaronman I don't think as an engineer, give a solution without knowing much about the problem is a good idea. Think about the case when you need to discuss a problem with non-technical background customer, you should be the one who collect the information. Furthermore, this is an interview, not a written test, so how you cooperate with your future colleague is also tested :)